# AppEngine autoscaling with initial instance size

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

For an application running on GCP AppEngine Flex, I run into transient high latency issue immediately after deployment when the new version can't catch up with the instance size of previous version.

Here's my scaling config:

```
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 5
  max_num_instances: 30
  cool_down_period_sec: 60
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.6
```

Traffic on the app is busier during day and instance count is high. Any deployment during this time means the new version takes 3-10 mins to ramp up to the previous versions instance count and results in high latency during this time.

I can do a manual traffic split by rolling out gradually which potentially has other benefits. Is there a way to set the initial instance size on the new version to match the previous version so the initial deployment goes smoothly without having to manually manage traffic.

Comment: See [migrating traffic](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating-traffic). Alternatively you could [split traffic](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/splitting-traffic) gradually between versions to ease onto the new (and from the old) version

Comment: No, there isn't that feature. The main problem here, is the slow scale up of AppEngine. Not a problem with a usual traffic, but problematic with sudden spikes (Like a version release). You might have a look on another container compliant solution that scale faster, like Cloud Run.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to roll out my own solution with traffic split to gradually ramp up. Would be a nice feature to have.